# .NET 3.5 Listbox Selected Values (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, listbox, multi-select, selectedvalue

I am BATTLING to get the selected values (please note VALUES not TEXT) from a Winforms Listbox that has multi-select enabled and has been bound to a database table getting the Name (as DisplayMember) and ID (as ValueMember) - I need the ID of the selected items.

The listbox control has properties for `SelectedValue` to get one of the selected items values, but not for all selected items values.

The `SelectedItems` property returns a `Listbox.SelectedObjectCollection` from which I cannot seem to extract the VALUES of the items.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some code to show how you're inserting items in the listbox?

Comment: The listbox has been bound to a database table getting the Name as DisplayMember and ID as ValueMember

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try casting each `object` in the collection to the desired `type`. For example, if my items are of type `Customer`, I could do something like this...

```
var selected = listBox1.SelectedItems;

foreach ( var item in selected )
{
    var singleCustomer = (Customer)item;
}
```

Now you can get any property you want from the `Customer`.

This is just a trivial example, but I'm sure you can apply the concept to your problem.

**UPDATE (after question was updated to indicate the Listbox is bound to table):**

If you're bound to a `DataTable`, you could try something like this (again, trivial but relevent):

```
var selected = listBox1.SelectedItems;

foreach ( var item in selected )
{
    var itemArray = ( (DataRowView)item ).Row.ItemArray;

    var name = itemArray[0];
    var id = itemArray[1];
}
```

Comment: This is the way I've done it when I add things manually, but I don't know how it works with bound controls.

Answer (score 3):

SelectedItems is what you want.

SelectedItem and SelectedValue are only different when you set DisplayMember and ValueMember. I don't think this is supported for Multi-select.

What type of Items are you adding to the listbox?

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the initial question - I have bound the control to a database table with Name as DisplayMember and ID as ValueMember. I want to get the selected items IDs

Comment: See @Steve Dignans answer, you probably need to cast to CustomerRow or something.

Answer (score 0):

Element **[0]** will be the "ValueMember", and element **[1]** will be the "DisplayMember". Assuming the OP's "ID" field is an integer, try the following:

```
int selectedCount = lstBxOb10Customer.SelectedItems.Count;
int[] selectedIDs = new int[selectedCount];
string[] selectedNames = new string[selectedCount];

for (int selected = 0; selected < selectedCount; selected++)
{
    var itemArray = ( (DataRowView)item ).Row.ItemArray;

    selectedIDs[selected]  = (int)itemArray[0];
    selectedNames[selected]  = (string)itemArray[1];
}
```