# How can I retrieve multiple selected listbox items and cast them to objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, listbox

Similar question: [.NET 3.5 Listbox Selected Values (Winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608568/net-3-5-listbox-selected-values-winforms)

I have a listbox populated using data binding to a collection of objects:

```
lstbDataFields.DisplayMember = "HumanReadable";
lstbDataFields.ValueMember = "DatabaseName";
lstbDataFields.DataSource = new BindingSource(ObjectCollection).OrderBy(d => d.HumanReadable), null);
```

I am looking for a way to pass the selected collection of these objects to a method. Something like this:

```
ProcessSelection((IEnumerable<ClassDataField>)lstbDataFields.SelectedItems);
```

This results in an `InvalidCastException`.

What's the best way to get a proper collection of my object type from this listbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ProcessSelection(lstbDataFields.SelectedItems.Cast<ClassDataField>())
```

should do what you want (add a System.Linq using statement)